# usage of "only" and "have"

Tags: meaning

If I say this:

> You don't have only what it takes to master English but all the languages.

For you, is it a compliment or an insult? The usage of "only" and "have" is a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 6):

This is not the sentence of a native English-speaker. Perhaps the intent is something more akin to the following:

> You have not only what it takes to master English, but all languages.

This is a compliment. "You" have "what it takes" (skill, aptitude, will) to master English, but beyond that, your skill, aptitude, and will would enable you to master any language.

Comment: I'd put "not only" even closer to "English" (to go with "all languages"), like: "You have what it takes to master not only English, but all languages."

Comment: +1 for explaining what the sentence mean, although it is not very well phrased.

Answer (score 5):

A person either *has* or *does not have* "what it takes to master English". To compliment a speaker by saying that he/she could do equally well in other languages, one would use *not only* or *not just* to introduce the sentiment that English is not the sole language the speaker could excel in.

These are compliments:

> - You have what it takes to master *not only* English *but also* any/every other language.
> - You have what it takes to master *not just* English *but [also]* all the languages.

These are insults:

> - You *don't* have what it takes to master English, *let alone* any other language.
> - You *don't* have what it takes to master English, or any other language *for that matter*.

Comment: +1 for providing examples of how the sentence should be said to be more correct.